# Washer drain hose depth in stack pipe

Tags: drain, hose

We had our new washing machine recently installed and I noticed tonight that it looks like the men who did the installation basically inserted whatever length of drain hose was available into the stack pipe (I’m not sure how far down it goes but I know it is more than 4 inches).  Is this definitely going to be a problem in the future or will it most likely be ok as it is?

Comment: Most factory drain hoses have a hook on the end that's about that length. If the plumbing is done properly it's fine.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as long as it does not go into the U-bend where the water trap is (prevents smalls coming up) then it will be fine.

I always make sure it goes in at least 6" as I have seen the force when it starts pumping to push the hose out - leading to some clearing up, one way to get a clean floor though :)